# How to remove some Azure functions logs?

Tags: azure, logging

Due to a bad manipulation I guess, some new logs appeared when I launch my Azure functions in the terminal.

The logs begin with : `MS_FUNCTION_LOGS 4` or `MS_FUNCTION_LOGS 5` or `MS_FUNCTION_METRICS` without any timestamp.

I tried changing log parameters and levels in the `host.json`.

I would like these logs to disappear as they clutter the logs in terminal appearing among all the other logs I chose to display.

The logs are very similar to those :
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/appsvc/azure-webjobs-sdk-script-y8o14/build/2.0.11719

Comment: Old question I know, but did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue for weeks until I talked to Microsoft technical support and we resolved it together.

For me, it was one of entries in `local.settings.json`. I had an entry called `CONTAINER_NAME: "<name>"` that caused the logs to be produced. Commenting this out returned the logs to their normal state.

The setting is apparently used for connection strings to specify containers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python

Comment: I'd been struggeling with this for 6 hours until i stumbled across your answer. Thank you so much! 
It is crazy they don't check for reserved names in `local.settings.json` on start. The Application Insights does not report this either, only `The listener for function 'Functions.<functionName>' was unable to start.`